# WebGL - discard fragments marked by vertex shader

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl, shader

I have a particle system created using *Three.js* in which each particle has an associated group of parameters (x, y, z, cost, hype, etc...) where I also keep the min/max of each. I've defined these as attributes and have created a uniform min/max entries. The uniform values are modified via sliders to act as a range filter.

```
attributes["aGain"] = { type: "f", value: [] };

uniforms["uGainMin"] = { type: "f", value: 10.0 };
uniforms["uGainMax"] = { type: "f", value: 15.0 };
```

Within the vertex shader I declare the attributes and a varying to act as a flag for the FS. 1.0 for visible and 0.0 for discarded.

```
varying float vectorVisible;
attribute float again;
```

I then compare each attribute to the corresponding uniform value.

```
if (aGain < uGainMin || aGain > uGainMax) { vectorVisible = 0.0; }
else { vectorVisible = 1.0; }
```

The `if` block has a condition for each attribute/uniform pairing.

In the fragment shader I check the value of `vertexVisible`.

```
if (vectorVisible == 0.0) discard;
```

What's happening is that my whole particle system is disappearing as soon as any filter slider value becomes greater than 0.

As a sanity check I've tried setting `vertexVisible` to 0.0 if the gl_Position.x component is less than 0 in the VS and that does cause those fragments to be discarded.

```
if (gl_Position.x < 0.0) vectorVisible = 0.0;
else vectorVisible = 1.0;
```

My attributes arrays are populated correctly and I'm not receiving any warnings on compile or during runtime. So, am I way off the mark with this whole thing?

[My related initial question regarding filtering by parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129375/threejs-how-can-i-use-a-shader-to-filter-vertices-by-property)

#### Update: Vertex Shader

Here's the whole vertex shader. I've had to work this into the THREE.js *particle basic* shader which is why it's setting the `gl_Position` earlier in the `main` function.

```
uniform float size;
uniform float scale;
attribute float ay;
uniform float uyMin;
uniform float uyMax;
attribute float ax;
uniform float uxMin;
uniform float uxMax;
attribute float az;
uniform float uzMin;
uniform float uzMax;
attribute float again;
uniform float ugainMin;
uniform float ugainMax;
#ifdef USE_COLOR
    varying vec3 vColor;
#endif
#ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
    varying vec4 vShadowCoord[ MAX_SHADOWS ];
    uniform mat4 shadowMatrix[ MAX_SHADOWS ];
#endif
void main() {
    #ifdef USE_COLOR
        #ifdef GAMMA_INPUT
            vColor = color * color;
        #else
            vColor = color;
        #endif
    #endif
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    #ifdef USE_SIZEATTENUATION
        gl_PointSize = size * ( scale / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );
    #else
        gl_PointSize = size;
    #endif
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    #if defined( USE_ENVMAP ) || defined( PHONG ) || defined( LAMBERT ) || defined (         USE_SHADOWMAP )
        #ifdef USE_SKINNING
            vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * skinned;
        #endif
        #if defined( USE_MORPHTARGETS ) && ! defined( USE_SKINNING )
            vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( morphed, 1.0 );
        #endif
        #if ! defined( USE_MORPHTARGETS ) && ! defined( USE_SKINNING )
            vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        #endif
    #endif
    #ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
        for( int i = 0; i < MAX_SHADOWS; i ++ ) {
            vShadowCoord[ i ] = shadowMatrix[ i ] * worldPosition;
        }
    #endif

    /***** Filters *****/
    if (ay < uyMin || ay > uyMax) gl_Position.xyz = vec3(2.);
    else if (ax < uxMin || ax > uxMax) gl_Position.xyz = vec3(2.);
    else if (az < uzMin || az > uzMax) gl_Position.xyz = vec3(2.);
    else if (again < ugainMin || again > ugainMax) gl_Position.xyz = vec3(2.);
}
```

#### JSFiddle

See it (not) working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/circuitBurn/X5J5q/18/).

Comment: these are point sprites? Do you need all this shadow and morph stuff?

Is this actually able to compile? I'm not sure whats going on in the last bit but ill update the answer with code.

Comment: All of the code above my filtering is from the THREE.js shader. It definitely compiles and I don't get any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: can you try gl_Position.xyz = vec3(2.); in the if else chain?

Comment: Hah, I just saw that I wasn't setting the gl_Position. I've added `gl_Position.xyz = vec3(2.);` but that doesn't change the behaviour though; the whole particle system still disappears.

Comment: meh :( well the only thing left to do is debug using colors, you can have a particle light up for example when it passes the test you're giving it, at least youll see whats going on there

Comment: I've tried :) The entire model changes color, much like it disappears. I really appreciate your help on both questions, thank you! I'll keep at it and update when I find a solution.

Comment: try to normalize your whatever position (uzmax etc) and see if it makes sense. If you are populating the buffers yourself you can do that and see if you can make sense out of it. Otherwise jsfiddle

Comment: I've added a working JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the new information:

add this:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    attributes:{
        aGain:{
            type:"f",
            value:null
        }
    },
    fragmentShader: fs_source....
```

I can't explain why, but it should work. :)

Without it i couldnt get the aGain to show up at all (they were all 0s as far as the gpu was concerned).

I've no idea what's the proper procedure with the answers. The other answer is about the clipping thing, this is for

**"Why is my custom three.js attribute buffer not showing up in the shader material?".**

Comment: You're welcome! You have no idea how much headache this gave me in the past :) glad i could save you some.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing this the wrong way again :)

Try having this as your fragment shader

```
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.);
}
```

and to simulate clipping try something along this lines of this in your vertex shader:

```
if (aGain < uGainMin || aGain > uGainMax) {
    gl_Position = vec4(vec3(2.),1.0);//this might work, move it out of NDC and clip
} else {
    gl_Position = yourlogic; // for example: projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

If you already know that you need to discard this object, why rasterize it and test against. Imagine if this was a large particle taking up most of your screen. The least you're doing is running the fragment shader and testing for each pixel. While you can get rid of it by moving one, or four verts for something like a particle.

Comment: Thought you might answer this one ;) Moving the vertex out of the NDC still makes the whole particle system disappear.

Comment: Hmmm, that shouldn't be happening. Can you update the question with the whole shader code?

Comment: Also, try to find the attribute array and see what kind of values  you actually got to the array (if any?). This can be tricky.

Comment: Updated with the shader. My array is actually populated with `int`s but I can't see that being a problem since I'm not doing equality comparisons. There is the expected number of values in each array, however.